# Is there a resource to query gene expression similarity? Stratified by sex?

Tags: gene-expression, sexual-dimorphism

We developed such a resource. The editors of "Bioinformatics" (at OUP) rejected the paper on the grounds that we did not run a comparison with "state-of-the-art" [similar] resources. Can someone help me find similar resources?
Link to our own resource, [ExFiles](http://unmtid-shinyapps.net/exfiles/).

Answer (score 2):

There are some similar resources, which at the same time do not mix the ingredients in the same way as your tool. Hope that pointing out the respective differences will help your rebuttal or resubmission! e.g.:

- A similar web service is part of [flyrnai](https://www.flyrnai.org/tools/dget/web/similar_genes/), where tissue-specific expression can also be compared based on sex, and genes can be queried by the similarity of their gene expression profile to other genes.
- A resource which has some conceptual relatedness regarding sex-specific similarity in gene expression, and which is also based on the GTEx dataset, has recently been published in the form of tables by [Gershoni et Pietrokovski, BMC Biol, 2017](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5297171/).
- A very nice and broad resource of high-quality gene expression profiles on individual tissues, but also on response to stimuli, is [EBI GXA](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/gxa/home). Though the web interface only allows to query sex-specific expression profiles, computationally minded people could readily compute (dis)similarity between samples after downloading the (well-structured) data dump of EBI GXA.
- A similar tool in terms of the visualization of sex-specific expression patterns is part of [gtexportal](https://gtexportal.org/home/), though it seems limited to displaying a single gene.